Flutter: Keyboard type changes automatically after unfocus called
I have several TextField's that go one after another and the keyboard type of which should be TextInputType.number. When switching between them, for some reason the keyboard sometimes changes to TextInputType.text for a second, and when unfocused it is generally clearly visible.
Here is how it looks like:

My code:
// ...
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    const Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    const Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    TextButton(
      onPressed: FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: const Text('Unfocus'),
    )
  ],
),
// ...

SDK:
Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2663184aa7 (3 months ago) • 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
Engine • revision 36335019a8
Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3

Flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4460], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0-rc3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version unknown)
    X Unable to determine VS Code version.
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!

I tried to change UnfocusDisposition to previouslyFocusedChild and some TextField's FocusNode parameters

I hope someone can verify it through a bug issue reference about Flutter or something.

I tested it out today; I had numerous counts of testing with different approaches and am still wondering why it behaves that way.
